# Converting an HTML table return from a PHP script to be in the format of ion-list for the Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

Currently I am developing an application on the Ionic framework. I have created a PHP file to pull 'Users' from my database and it is currently returning them in an HTML table format.

In the services section of the framework I have set up the 'AJAX' call which is pulling this information:

```
.service('getUsers', function($http){
    var Users;
    return {
        getEmps: function(){
            return $http.get('http://#####.#####/#####/#####/getUsers.php').then(function(items) { 
                Users = items.data; return Users; 
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Then inside my controller I am doing the following:

```
       getUsers.getEmps().then(function(data) {
       $scope.Employees = data;
          console.log($scope.Employees); 
       });
```

This successfully returns the table to the console:

JohnSmith

I am trying to create the a multidimensional array from this. I tried to do the following:

```
 var details = $('tr').map(function (i, row) {

    // creating an Object to return:
    return {
        'First Name': row.cells[0].textContent,
        'Last Name': row.cells[1].textContent
    }
    // converting the map into an Array:
    }).get();

    console.log(details);
```

However I am having no luck returning an array which I can use to pass into the 
ionic frameworks - ion-list.

Comment: The output for the HTML in the console looks like the following: <table><tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return your data in JSON format from PHP. You can encode any array to JSON using `json_encode($array);` and print it out. Also remember to set the content type in PHP to JSON: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`.
Once fetched in JSON format you can access your data like any other JavaScript object, so there's no need to parse tables, etc. 
If you need to display the data as a table just loop through it using ng-repeat. 
Sending the whole HTML table(code) over HTTP is very inefficient.

Comment: Accept the answer if it's what you were looking for.